# How to inject an ArrayList into a JTable, in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, swing

I am starting to use the IntelliJ IDEA (IDE) and I was doing a *Swing*  project. For the moment I made an `ArrayList` to simulate the database to see if everything was going well. I try to connect said `ArrayList` to a `JTable` as I normally did in NetBeans, but the data is not reflected. I don't know if someone could give me a way to inject that `ArrayList`, please.

Because of what the `JTable` is, I created it using the IntelliJ editor itself, that is, I didn't use any code.

I tried to do it as I did in NetBeans but it didn't work. I tried to do it with a tutorial, but that didn't work either.

This is the `ArrayList`:

```
public class DatabaseLibros {

    public static ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    void cargarLibrosDB() {
        Book book;

        // Libro 1
        book = new Book("El señor de los anillos", "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Fantasía", "978-84-450-7570-9");
        books.add(book);

        // Libro 2
        book = new Book("Cien años de soledad", "Gabriel García Márquez", "Realismo mágico", "978-84-376-0374-7");
        books.add(book);

        // Libro 3
        book = new Book("1984", "George Orwell", "Distopía", "978-84-670-5189-7");
        books.add(book);
    }

    // Método para obtener todos los libros de la base de datos
    public static ArrayList<Book> obtenerLibros() {
        return books;
    }

    // Método para agregar un nuevo libro a la base de datos
    public static void agregarLibro(Book nuevoBook) {
        books.add(nuevoBook);
    }
}
```

Here is the logic of the `JFrame` window:

```
public class PantallaPrincipal extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JTable jTable;
    private JButton salirButton;
    private JLabel txtLeft;

    public PantallaPrincipal() {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(30, 0);
        jTable.setModel(tableModel);

        tableModel.addColumn("Título");
        tableModel.addColumn("Autor");
        tableModel.addColumn("Género");
        tableModel.addColumn("ISBN");

        // Configurar el contenido del JFrame
        add(panel);
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        salirButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                Container principal = new Container();
                principal.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use `DefaultTableModel` as a data model / source for the JTable. Have you looked up any resources which has some guidance, like : [Java Swing - How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you starting by reading through [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  You would also benefit from understanding concepts like [Dependency Injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+dependency+injection) and the [observer pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+observer+pattern)

Personally, I would start by creating a custom `TableModel` which would take an instance of the data source (an instance of `DatabaseLibros`).  To do this, I'd create a class which extends from `AbstractTableModel`, this way you can easily configure and reuse the model.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JTable(new BookTableModel(new DatabaseLibros())));
        }
    }

    public class BookTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = new String[]{
            "Título",
            "Autor",
            "Género",
            "ISBN"
        };

        private DatabaseLibros database;

        public BookTableModel(DatabaseLibros database) {
            this.database = database;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return database.obtenerLibros().size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnNames[column];
        }



        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Book book = database.obtenerLibros().get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: return book.getTitle();
                case 1: return book.getAuthor();
                case 2: return book.getPublisher();
                case 3: return book.getIsbn();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Book {
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private String publisher;
        private String isbn;

        public Book(String title, String author, String publisher, String isbn) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.publisher = publisher;
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public String getPublisher() {
            return publisher;
        }

        public String getIsbn() {
            return isbn;
        }

    }

    public class DatabaseLibros {
        private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

        public DatabaseLibros() {
            // Libro 1
            books.add(new Book("El señor de los anillos", "J.R.R. Tolkien", "Fantasía", "978-84-450-7570-9"));

            // Libro 2
            books.add(new Book("Cien años de soledad", "Gabriel García Márquez", "Realismo mágico", "978-84-376-0374-7"));

            // Libro 3
            books.add(new Book("1984", "George Orwell", "Distopía", "978-84-670-5189-7"));
        }

        // Método para obtener todos los libros de la base de datos
        public ArrayList<Book> obtenerLibros() {
            return books;
        }

        // Método para agregar un nuevo libro a la base de datos
        public void agregarLibro(Book nuevoBook) {
            books.add(nuevoBook);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, I'd be careful using `static` in the way you are, it could easily come back to haunt you.